# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined when refactoring code

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to make this code easier:

```
links.forEach(function(link) {
    link.source = nodes[link.source] ||
        (nodes[link.source] = {
            name: link.source
        });
    link.target = nodes[link.target] ||
        (nodes[link.target] = {
            name: link.target
        });
    console.log(nodes)
});
```

So, I refactored it like this:

```
links.forEach(function(link) {
    if (nodes[link.source] == null) {
        nodes[link.source] = {
            name: link.source
        };
    } else if (nodes[link.target] == null) {
        nodes[link.target] = {
            name: link.target
        };
    } else {
        console.log('Not problem');
    }
});
```

However, now I get this error:

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

This is the full original code:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

 .node {
   fill: #4D00DD;
   stroke: #fff;
   stroke-width: 2px;
  }

 .link {
   stroke: #777;
   stroke-width: 8px;
  }

</style>
<body>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var width = 1080,
        height = 960;

    var links = [
      { source : "Baratheon", target : "Lannister"},
      { source : "Baratheon", target : "Stark"},
      { source : "Lannister", target : "Stark"},

    ];

    var nodes = {};

    // parse links to nodes

    links.forEach(function(link) {
      link.source = nodes[link.source] ||
        (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
      link.target = nodes[link.target] ||
        (nodes[link.target] = {name: link.target});
      console.log(nodes)
    });

   // add svg to our body

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var force = d3.layout.force()
        .size([width, height])
        .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
        .links(links)
        .on("tick", tick)
        .linkDistance(600)
        .start();

    var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
        .data(links)
        .enter().append("line")
        .attr("class", "link")

    var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
        .data(force.nodes())
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("r", width * 0.03);

    function tick(e) {

      node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
          .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
          .call(force.drag);

      link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
          .attr('y1', function(d) { return d.source.y; })
          .attr('x2', function(d) { return d.target.x; })
          .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: There is no `push` in your code sample.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I made a lot of changes in your question, please look at it carefully, paying attention to what I changed and why I did it. Also, please, head the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to make that block easier to read, which is a very nice exercise. However, you forgot something.

In the original code, this assignment...

```
link.source = nodes[link.source] || (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
```

... means, in a very verbose way:

> Does `nodes[link.source]` exist? If yes, make `link.source = nodes[link.source]`. If no, make `nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source}`, and then make `link.source = nodes[link.source]`.

But in your `if` logic you're never setting `link.source` if `nodes[link.source]` exists!

Also, you don't need:

```
if (nodes[link.source] == null) {
```

A simple `if (!nodes[link.source]) {` will work.

Finally, drop that `else`. The second `if` **must** be evaluated, regardless the result of the first `if`.

All that being said, this should be your refactored code:

```
links.forEach(function(link) {
  if (!nodes[link.source]) {
    nodes[link.source] = {
      name: link.source
    }
  };
  //Look, Ma, no 'else' here!
  if (!nodes[link.target]) {
    nodes[link.target] = {
      name: link.target
    }
  };
  //add these lines:
  link.source = nodes[link.source];
  link.target = nodes[link.target];
});
```

And here is the running demo:

```js
var width = 600,
  height = 300;

var links = [{
    source: "Baratheon",
    target: "Lannister"
  }, {
    source: "Baratheon",
    target: "Stark"
  }, {
    source: "Lannister",
    target: "Stark"
  },

];

var nodes = {};

links.forEach(function(link) {
  if (!nodes[link.source]) {
    nodes[link.source] = {
      name: link.source
    }
  };
  if (!nodes[link.target]) {
    nodes[link.target] = {
      name: link.target
    }
  };
  link.source = nodes[link.source];
  link.target = nodes[link.target];
});

// add svg to our body

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([width, height])
  .nodes(d3.values(nodes))
  .links(links)
  .on("tick", tick)
  .linkDistance(50)
  .start();

var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
  .data(links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("class", "link")

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(force.nodes())
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", width * 0.03);

function tick(e) {

  node.attr("cx", function(d) {
      return d.x;
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return d.y;
    })
    .call(force.drag);

  link.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr('y1', function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr('x2', function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot to your kind answering
But I have a question
I think 'link.source', 'link.target' is meanless. Because 'link.source' already has value like "Baratheon" or "Lannister".
So, why "link.source", "link.target" assignment lines are necessary?
I don't know where these lines are use.

Comment: They are different: `links` is the array. `link`, which is just a parameter of the `forEach` function, is the object, and it could have any other name.

Comment: Please check my Another answer not comment.
I need your help.

Comment: I'm so sorry about my huge mistake.

Comment: @specialscene no worries. Thanks for posting it as a new question.