# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined when refactoring code, part 2

Tags: javascript, d3.js

For context, [this is my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48165794/cannot-read-property-push-of-undefined-when-refactoring-code)

I checked my code using the code below:

```
links.forEach(function(link) {
   // check part1
   console.log("before",link.source)

   link.source = nodes[link.source] ||
       (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});

   // check part2
   console.log("After",link.source)
   });
```

Unfortunately, I'm still confused.

Because of `link` is a part of `links`, I think one of `link` is:

```
{source : "Baratheon", target : "Lannister"}
```

So,

```
console.log("before", link.source) -> Baratheon 
console.log("After", link.source) -> {name: "Baratheon"}
```

What does it mean? Why `link.source` changed? I think `var nodes` have values not `link.source`.

Additionally I checked `var nodes` have values without `link.source` assignment like my incorrect code.

Comment: Once again, I heavily edited your question. Last time I do this. Please, read about how to format your question in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry again.
I will read about format in the Help Center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because I don't know exactly what you know or not in Javascript, I will go in details like if I was explaining to a beginner.

I will rewrite the line differently to make you understand what was going on here:

```
link.source = nodes[link.source] ||
   (nodes[link.source] = {name: link.source});
```

For this, we should note that:

> According to: `A = B || C;`
>
> - `A` will takes the value of `C` if `B` if "falsey" (`null`, `0`, `false`, `undefined` or `""`)
> - `A` will be equal to `B` if `B` is not falsey.

> According to: `A = (B = C);`
>
> - `B` will take the value of `C` first
> - `A` will take the new value of `B` (so the value of `C` too)

So for your problem, we can sum up into that:

link.source will take the value of:

- `nodes[link.source]`, if `nodes[link.source]` is not falsey
- `{name: link.source}`, in other cases (and `nodes[link.source]` will took `{name: link.source}` as value at the same time)

So, here I think that `nodes[link.source]` was `undefined` before execution; and so, because `undefined` is falsey; and because `link.source` was `Baratheon` before execution of this line; `link.source` took `{name: "Baratheon"}` as value